# Some logical error in alpha beta pruning function

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chess, alpha-beta-pruning, minmax

I am building a chess game in Python, and I was trying to add AI in it. I have successfully implemented the min max algorithm and it is working just fine, but when I am trying the alpha beta pruning, the moves generated by both of them differ.

```
def alphabeta(self, color, alpha, beta, depth):
        if (depth == 0):
            return self.evaluator.evaluateBoard(), []
        # self.posEval += 1
        allMoves = self.getAllMoves(color)
        bestMove = []
        toBreak = False
        if (self.isMaximize(color)):
            maxEval = -9999
            for src in allMoves:
                for dest in allMoves[src]:
                    self.board.movePiece(src, dest)
                    if (self.movements.isMate(self.getOppositeColor(color))):
                        maxEval = CHECKMATE
                        bestMove = [[src.createNewCopy(), dest.createNewCopy(), copy.deepcopy(maxEval)]]
                        toBreak = True
                        self.board.revertMove(src, dest)
                        print("Checkmate was found!!!")
                        break
                    eval, temp = self.alphabeta(self.getOppositeColor(color), alpha, beta, depth - 1)
                    self.posEval += 1
                    self.board.revertMove(src, dest)
                    if (eval > maxEval):
                        maxEval = eval
                        bestMove = [[src.createNewCopy(), dest.createNewCopy(), copy.deepcopy(maxEval)]]
                    elif (eval == maxEval):
                        bestMove.append([src.createNewCopy(), dest.createNewCopy(), copy.deepcopy(maxEval)])
                    alpha = max(alpha, eval)
                    if (beta <= alpha):
                        toBreak = True
                        break
                if (toBreak):
                    break
            return maxEval, bestMove
        
        else:

            minEval = 9999
            for src in allMoves:
                for dest in allMoves[src]:
                    self.board.movePiece(src, dest)
                    if (self.movements.isMate(self.getOppositeColor(color))):
                        minEval = -CHECKMATE
                        bestMove = [[src.createNewCopy(), dest.createNewCopy(), copy.deepcopy(minEval)]]
                        toBreak = True
                        self.board.revertMove(src, dest)
                        print("Checkmate was found!!!")
                        break
                    eval, temp = self.alphabeta(self.getOppositeColor(color), alpha, beta, depth - 1)
                    self.posEval += 1
                    self.board.revertMove(src, dest)
                    if (eval < minEval):
                        minEval = eval
                        bestMove = [[src.createNewCopy(), dest.createNewCopy(), copy.deepcopy(minEval)]]
                    elif (eval == minEval):
                        bestMove.append([src.createNewCopy(), dest.createNewCopy(), copy.deepcopy(minEval)])
                    beta = min(eval, beta)
                    if (beta <= alpha):
                        toBreak = True
                        break
                if (toBreak):
                    break
            return minEval, bestMove
```

I think that the error is in the line eval == maxEval and eval == minEval, as this function is generating some extra moves. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: This is going to be too much work for someone to debug without more specific information on what you think the problem is.  Can you make a minimum reproducible example?  For example set up an example game state and a move by the 'AI' that you think is incorrect and what you think the optimal move should be. You could also provide some helpful links to the theory behind these algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I am just asking that I had created two functions minmax and alphabeta. I have used the minmax code for alpha beta function as well, but just added the part where it breaks out of the loop and stops checking a tree further to save time(If you want I can attach minmax code as well). I am not asking to check my entire code, as I am pretty sure that the main logic is correct(as it is working fine in min max). I think that either I am making a mistake in pruning the branches(less likely) or while comparing moves with same score,i.e.,(eval == maxEval)or(eval == minEval)

Comment: Also what I'm trying to do here is basically get the best possible move, but if there are multiple moves with same score, then I want to return all of them in the list (which is why I am appending the bestMoves list when the calculated score and best score are equal), which I can then use to add randomness in moves...The alpha beta function is generating the best moves, but it also generates some moves which are not good for that scenario (considering score) (and not being generated by min max function). Thanks again.

Comment: Alpha beta pruning will at the time of *pruning* return a value that is not the *exact* value, but a good-enough value to initiate the pruning. Specifically when alpha *equals* beta, you will get positives on `eval == maxEval` which you would not get with plain minimax. My guess(!) is that you will avoid this situation if you would change `beta <= alpha` to `beta < alpha`. But your question does not have code with which we can reproduce your problem (and that is a *requirement* for these types of questions on Stack Overflow), so no way to check if this is indeed what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought the same way you did and I have already implemented and tested what you said, and it is producing accurate results now, but as expected, the speed has reduced drastically. But, I mean, aren't min-max and alpha-beta pruning expected to generate the same output and Isn't there a  way to optimize this algorithm?

Comment: They are guaranteed to produce the same result *if* you select the single best move. If you need the ties too, then you need to relax the pruning as I suggested. If that has a heavy impact on the performance, then that indicates your evaluation function is not fine-grained enough  and often returns the same value for many different positions.

Comment: Yeah, I think that the validation of checkmate at every recursion call is adding a lot of overhead, anyways Thanks a lot!